# Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in $G$ and $\gamma \sim_G0$. Prove that if $f(z)=g(z)$ for $z\in\gamma$, then $f(z)=g(z)$ for $z$ in $\gamma$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in the region $G$ and $\gamma \sim$ $_G$ $0$. Prove that if $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in\gamma$, then $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z$ inside $\gamma$.

Comment: A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka ?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you already know, but one way to prove it is by using the Cauchy integral formula

$$nf(z_0)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac1{z-z_0}f(z)dz$$

where $n$ is the number of times that the curve $\gamma$ winds around $z_0.$